# Count visitors of pages in react

Tags: reactjs

I'am still learning to code. Current I' am building a news-site as mern-stack. I have a component in which I map over the newsitems, now in the next component I want to have a ranking-list with the ten most-clicked articles. The data comes from a data.js, in which I have an objectEntrie with count: 0 what I would like to increment, and afterwards I want to sort. I hope, someone can help me, because I totally stuck.
Thanks.

```
const News = () => {
   
    const handleClick = (section)=>{
        
      }
    
  return <Container>
            <Hr/>
            <NewsTitleHolder>
                <NewsTitle>NEWS</NewsTitle>
                <IoIosArrowForward style={{fontSize:"26px", color: "var(--gray)"}}/>
            </NewsTitleHolder>
            <ArticleHolder>
                {
                    mainnews.map((item)=>(
                        <Link to={{pathname: `/${item.ressort}`}} className="link" key={item.id}>
                        <Section key={item.id} onClick={()=>handleClick(item.id)}>
                            <NewsImg src={item.img} alt={item.id} title={item.title}/>
                            <NewsRessort>{item.ressort}</NewsRessort>
                            <NewsTheme>{item.theme}</NewsTheme>
                            <ContentTitle>{item.title}</ContentTitle>
                            <Content>{item.content}</Content>
                        </Section>
                        </Link>
                    ))
                }
            </ArticleHolder>
  </Container>;
};

export default News;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass item.count to handleClick function instead of item.id and inside handleClick increment it. Then pass an array that consists of news item to a ranking list component via props, but before that make ordering of the array and extract only ten most clicked news items. You can also use Redux to store all news items there and then you can access all news from any component without passing it through a sequence of props

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped you. Have a nice day!